# How to Re-Write SEO friendly URLs in MVC 2 between main site and it's sub domain site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, seo

I had two web sites build on MVC

Site1:
mydemosite.co.uk

Site2:
subdomain.mydemosite.co.uk

There is a "channel area" link on site 1 but when user click on it I take him to the site2 like this and from there the page is served, the location of this link is as follows

LinkA:
subdomain.mydemosite.co.uk\channelarea

But I want is to re-write above URL LinkA for SEO purpose as given below in LinkB

LinkB:
mydemosite.co.uk\channelarea

I am confused about how to handle above situation for SEO should my LinkA is like LinkB before user click on it or I just change change URL to LinkB when target page is displaying

I dont know how to do it it MVC 2?

Any example will be very useful

Answer (score 0):

Why not put your Site2 in a virtual application under the main site in IIS

In IIS Manager right click on site1 and select 'Add Application'
Then your Site2 link could be something like /site2/channelarea